# How to make an arc facing sideways - python

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I am trying to make a game that requires an arc that is facing right or left but all I can get is up or down.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

tk = Tk() 
c = Canvas(tk, height=500, width=500)    
 
x = 100
y = 395
x2 = 125

archer = c.create_oval(x, y, x + 20, y + 20, fill='blue')
bow = c.create_line(x2, y + 10, x2, y - 10)
string = c.create_arc(x2 + 100, y + 10, x2, y - 10, extent=180, style=ARC)

c.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance ; )

Comment: Have you tried experimenting with the arc options, such as `start`?

Comment: Thanks but, I don't know how to use most of them yet, can you give me an example?

Comment: I recommend doing some experimentation. For example, create four arcs with a `start` value of 0, 45, 90, and 180, to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it out. I hope you have a good day